# Need of source for the 2nd half of "On sense and reference"

Tags: philosophy-of-language

As you know, much of the second half of “On Sense and Reference” is devoted to carefully considering when subordinate clauses and embedded sentences contribute customary or indirect senses to the thoughts expressed.

Now in a self study manner, it's not much clear to me and i need some extra **source** other than the article itself to explain me those with more clarity/detail.

Any help would be thanked in depth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Kevin Klement, [Frege and the Logic of Sense and Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415514665) (2002) and Mark Textor, [Routledge Philosophy GuideBook to Frege on Sense and Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/041541962X) (2010).

*Note* : you can try also "googleing" :

> frege on indirect sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at both, however i think the second one seems more general and fluent than the first.
Useful comment anyway...

Comment: @user4970 - You are right; the first one is more interested to the logical aspects, while the second one is a "logico-philosophical" commentary to Frege's theory.

Comment: Surely the first would be such a good help! Because I myself do mathematical logic and I'm new to the field philosophy of language!
As i check your profile it seems you are also a fan of Mathematical logic! By the way I would like to know your personal technical comment on the first source you mentioned!

Comment: @user4970 - Kevin Klement is teach logic and phi.of language (check on the web) : he had produced very interesting studies on Frege, Russell, etc. The aim of the above book is to develop a "logic of sense and denotation" (was alredy studied by Alonzo Church); the topic is complex and the result is - for my limited understanding - doubtful. But the first part of the book is a good introduction to Frege's logic.